# Postgres RDS IOPS increased

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We found that IOPS for postrgres RDS has increased and it increased billing for our clients, business want us to check what has caused this increase IOPS and can we decrease it.
Please suggest on this.

Comment: Currently we are having Provisioned IOPS.

Comment: "business want us to check what has caused this increase IOPS and can we decrease it" Maybe it's just as simple as the database is being more used/requested this periode by the users or applications..  Or the queried data is become larger vs the other periode meaning more IOPS is required.

Comment: Do we have any way to find session/sql's causing more IOPS operation on database.

Comment: "Currently we are having Provisioned IOPS" The secret AWS doesn't want you to know is: Provisioned IOPS is really bad value for the money.. For example.. Locking up a b-tree index can be annywhere between 1 or 4 IOPS per record. Writing a record in the b-tree index also can require between 1 or 4 IOPS per record for the lookup .. That's only the lookup getting the data also might require 1 IOPS (FULL table scan) or more when indexes are used which requires more IOPS to get the data from the table..

Comment: ... it's just the way the b-tree index algoritme works it can require even more index lookups for read and write lookups when the table becomes larger in the millions or billions.. With other words you might be better off using fixed prices for the GB's you use.